# joomla login module redirection not working in other secondary languages

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Hi I have set up a site that uses

Joomla 3.2.3
php 5.5.10

I am running 2 languages on the site.

I have set up a menu item that displays the login module each language and a login module for each language
I have set up a in each module a different 'Login Redirection Page' to point to the appropriate language home page.

The default English languages works correctly and once a user logs in, it takes them to the specific page, but for some reason i can't work out, the other language (spanish) Redirect won't go to any other page that I set in the 'Login Redirection Page' settings - it simply takes them to the default english login page, and ignores the settings?

I have double checked all the menu and modules settings for both and they are the same expect for the language settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the 'Automatic Language Change' to Yes?

Plug ins -> System - Language Filter -> Basic options

Comment: sadly yes, its set to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try changing Plugin Manager -> System - Language Filter -> Automatic Language Change -> NO

The problem is that Joomla automatically changes to the default site language, and then goes to the default login page.